# variable in string in parameter

Tags: javascript, function

I'm working on a table constructor for one of my larger projects but the variables in the content I'm trying to send to the constructor function evaluate before they are sent. Here is a cut down version of the function that should show my problem:

```
x = 0;

tableConstructor(["<p>" + x + "</p>", "<div>" + x + "</div>"]);

function tableConstructor (tableContent) {
    for (x = 0; x < 2; x++) {
        window["row" + x] = tableContent[x];

        console.log(window["row" + x]);
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
<p>0</p>
<div>0</div>
```

But what I want is:

```
<p>0</p>
<div>1</div>
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3):

> Use `++x` while passing argument or `x++` like this `"<p>" + (x++) + "<p/>"`

`Post-increment` returns the copy of the original value.

**Using `increment operators`:**

```js
var y = 0;

function tableConstructor(tableContent) {
  for (var x = 0; x < 2; x++) {
    window["row" + x] = tableContent[x];
    console.log(window["row" + x]);
  }
}
tableConstructor(["<p>" + y + "<p/>", "<div>" + (++y) + "<div/>"]);
```

```html
<script src="http://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
```

**Using DOM Api:**

```js
var y = 0;
function tableConstructor(tableContent) {
  for (var x = 0; x < tableContent.length; x++) {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = tableContent[x];
    var elem = div.firstChild;
    elem.innerHTML = x;
    var wanted = elem.outerHTML;
    window["row" + x] = wanted;
    console.log(window["row" + x]);
  }
}
tableConstructor(["<p>" + y + "<p/>", "<div>" + y + "<div/>"]);
```

```html
<script src="http://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
```

**Using Regex(replacing `digit`):**

```js
var y = 0;

function tableConstructor(tableContent) {
  for (var x = 0; x < 2; x++) {
    window["row" + x] = tableContent[x].replace(/\d/, x);
    console.log(window["row" + x]);
  }
}
tableConstructor(["<p>" + y + "<p/>", "<div>" + (++y) + "<div/>"]);
```

```html
<script src="http://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: How about `x + 1` instead?

Comment: It will work as well..But as you have commented this, is there any other advantage of using `x+1` ?

Comment: I would say there is no any particular reason, it's just a preference.

Comment: `++x` will increase the value of x by 1. `x+1` will not.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, but that wasn't what I meant. I want the function to evaluate x dynamically and not have it based on what I pass the function when I call it.

Comment: _Dynamically_ ? Based on what ?

Comment: Based on the value of x within the function, depending on its iteration.

Comment: @JackCoggins, You can use `.replace` if you want to replace inner digit of the `string` => `tableContent[x].replace(/\d/, x)`

Comment: Or you can do this using DOM and creating fake `div` element like this: https://jsfiddle.net/bhmz1jab/

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your own example is that the strings that go into your array are created at that very moment when `x` is still `0`. Changing `x` afterwards doesn't help much.

Here's one very overengineered example to do things, where there's a seperate `x` in the loop and inside a "builder":

```js
function createEntryBuilder() {
  // This is a *different* `x` from the one in the for loop.
  var x = 0;
  
  return function(tagName) {
    var tag = document.createElement(tagName);
    tag.innerHTML = x;
    x = x + 1;
    return tag;
  }
}

var builder = createEntryBuilder();

tableConstructor(["p", "div"]);

function tableConstructor (tableContent) {
    for (var x = 0; x < 2; x++) {
        var element = builder(tableContent[x]);
        window["row" + x] = element;
        console.log(window["row" + x]);
        document.body.appendChild(element);
    }
}
```

```css
p { background: pink; }
div { background: khaki; }
```

If you *want* to use the loop's number you could change it up to this:

```js
function createEntryBuilder() {
  return function(tagName, x) {
    var tag = document.createElement(tagName);
    tag.innerHTML = x;
    x = x + 1;
    return tag;
  }
}

var builder = createEntryBuilder();

tableConstructor(["p", "div"]);

function tableConstructor (tableContent) {
    for (var x = 0; x < 2; x++) {
        var element = builder(tableContent[x], x);
        window["row" + x] = element;
        console.log(window["row" + x]);
        document.body.appendChild(element);
    }
}
```

```css
p { background: pink; }
div { background: khaki; }
```

Answer (score 0):

What if you use some kind of template, like this:

```js
function tableConstructor (tableContent) {
    for (var x = 0; x < tableContent.length; x++) {
        window["row" + x] = tableContent[x].replace("{x}",x);
        console.log(window["row" + x]);
    }
}

tableConstructor(["<p>{x}</p>", "<div>{x}</div>", "<i>{x}</i>"]);
```

This way you can do something like this:

```
tableConstructor(["<p>hey variable x is {x}</p>", "<div>now is {x}</div>", "<i>and it changed to this {x}</i>"]);
```